# RestTemplate shows page not found but no error exception

Tags: java, spring, glassfish, resttemplate

**EDITED**

i have a problem with my application. I am using glassfish 4 and java 8, because my environment can't take spring 5, so i'm using spring 4 instead. I just need a few libraries to access API from another server. One of the function is RestTemplate. Everytime restTemplate.exchange is triggered, it always give HTTP 500 Error. But no exception at all. I know this is HTTP 500 error by looking at web.xml. There is no Exception message, even i've tried to add try-catch. It happens on my production server, in my development server, it's running well. In my laptop, it's running well. Can you please help me with this?

Here is my log4j

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2=INFO,stdout
log4j.logger.org.apache.struts2=INFO,stdout
log4j.logger.uk.ltd.getahead.dwr=WARN, stdout
log4j.logger.freemarker.cache=INFO,stdout
log4j.logger.com.jwebs=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARNING, stdout

log4j.appender.R.File=application.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil=error
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack=error
```

Here i attach my code

```
        RestTemplate templatet = new RestTemplate();

        String url = "http:someurl";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Some header to get", "get");
        headers.add("Some authorization", "authorization");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> sapSecurity = templatet.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
```

Thank you

Comment: `headersa` is this a typo???. Shouldn't it be `headers`

Comment: page not found is 404, not 500

Comment: wait. let me edit my post

Comment: there you go. really need some suggestions

Comment: 500 is a server error, whereas you've provided your client side code. I would suggest you to look at the server logs and server app logs.

Comment: I've checked it, like i said. there is no exception at all. it works well in my local env. but when it goes to production, boom. error. it's like there is a library exception who doesn't show up in my log

Comment: try turning on debug logs on server

Comment: Can you give me suggestions what should i add with this debug log? I'll show you mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Seems like there is a crash in the library. Java read the same library but different version. I have spring.jar and spring-web.4.3.6-RELEASE.jar, that's why it's crashed and didn't show any exception. The only way to extract the exception, is through the servlet.
You can see the following tutorial by Tutorialspoint:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to do the following, so that you can get more information about what's happening on the server by reading the logs.

```
try {
     ResponseEntity<String> sapSecurity = templatet.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();//this stackTrace should appear in the Glassfish log file
}
```

Also, you should check if your app is not being blocked by some kind of network policy on the server.

Comment: Well, i have solved it. I already added try-catch. But it's not my code fault